# Is there a way to group timestamps by every rolling 24 hours so I can retrieve a sum in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

For example, I have

```
race_start_time     race_end_time      total_money_raised
2020-05-17 8:50:24  2020-05-17 12:12:43 100
2020-05-22 17:29:19 2020-05-22 19:44:46 98
2020-05-06 17:22:51 2020-05-06 19:11:41 84
2020-05-06 19:25:15 2020-05-06 20:35:53 68
2020-05-06 15:04:52 2020-05-06 17:05:13 90
2021-01-11 13:32:45 2021-01-11 15:57:46 104
2020-05-26 13:19:05 2020-05-26 16:05:12 105
2020-12-05 7:08:31  2020-12-05 10:22:00 77
```

this data is all for the same ID - I want to see how much money they have raised in a rolling 24 hours **FROM THE START OF RACE, like from 2020-05-17 8:50:24 to 2020-05-18 8:50:24, from 2020-05-22 17:29:19 to 2020-05-23 17:29:19 etc

output desired

```
dates_here total_sum_raise
group24h   55
group24h   242
group24h   89
```

Comment: Please explain what "group24h" means.  Rolling sums usually don't change the number of rows, so it is a bit unclear what you are asking for.  How is "55" calculated?  It seems to have nothing to do with the sample data.

Comment: Mhmm, I don't mean rolling sums - more like rolling hour. I want to see if they can hit a certain sum within a 24 hour period. the 55 from the "output desired" is a random number - was displaying the desired set up. Should have explained that! Thank you for the clarifying questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would love for window frames to work on a value or date range like this, but they don't.  So, you probably have to do a self-join on your table on a date range, instead.  Something along these lines (ignore CTE, obviously, that's just how I created your sample data):

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
      ('2020-05-17 8:50:24'::timestamp,'2020-05-17 12:12:43'::timestamp, 100),
      ('2020-05-22 17:29:19'::timestamp,'2020-05-22 19:44:46'::timestamp,  98),
      ('2020-05-06 17:22:51'::timestamp,'2020-05-06 19:11:41'::timestamp,  84),
      ('2020-05-06 19:25:15'::timestamp,'2020-05-06 20:35:53'::timestamp,  68),
      ('2020-05-06 15:04:52'::timestamp,'2020-05-06 17:05:13'::timestamp,  90),
      ('2021-01-11 13:32:45'::timestamp,'2021-01-11 15:57:46'::timestamp,  104),
      ('2020-05-26 13:19:05'::timestamp,'2020-05-26 16:05:12'::timestamp,  105),
      ('2020-12-05 7:08:31'::timestamp,'2020-12-05 10:22:00'::timestamp, 77)
    ) x (race_start_time, race_end_time, total_money_raised)
)

SELECT a.race_start_time, a.race_end_time, a.total_money_raised, SUM(b.total_money_raised)
FROM x a
JOIN x b
  ON b.race_start_time BETWEEN a.race_start_time AND dateadd(day,1,a.race_start_time)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: this is beautiful!!!! thank you for helping with all the limited information i gave. this is exactly what i needed.